# Is it possible to access and retrieve data from another PC's data file via USB?

Tags: c++, automation, modbus

In my application I have 2 PCs.

PC A will be the PC that only aggregates data. I would like PC B to read data from PC A via USB. Although I am not sure if this is possible. When I research this subject I notice many applications utilize a modbus protocol yet I am not sure what that is. I would think there would be a library in c++ where I can access PC A's USB port, locate data file from PC B, and retrieve the data.

I am currently implementing my project in c++. Any information on the subject is appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what platform you are running on. C++ by itself has no knowledge of USB devices. That is an OS-specific function. Also, I would recommend you doing this through the network stack, not USB. It is easier and less complex.

Comment: @rlam12 The PC aggregating data would be running on either Raspbian or Microsoft Windows Embedded Standard 7E. When you say "network stack" are you referring to communication protocols such as Modbus or CANbus?

Comment: By network stack I mean a TCP/IP packet network between both computers. You would communicate through Ethernet or WiFi instead of USB between both computers. Your job will be to serialize the data in a network friendly way and send it upon request. Both Linux and Windows offer C networking APIs but you can of course get cross platform network APIs that were made in C++. Good ones are either Poco::Net or Boost:Asio. There is also ModBus over TCP/IP if you want to Google that and are interested in the subject.